# Одновременый ввод в несколько яйчеек в DataGrid

Tags: c#, datagrid, visual-studio

Можно ли как то сделать одновременный ввод в несколько яйчеек? Выделить нужные яйчейки, начать вводить, и вводились бы данные сразу во все выделенные яйчейки.

Answer (score 1):

Например, сделайте колонку чекбоксов, отдельное поле ввода и кнопку "ввести". в обработчике клика кнопки будете пробегать по всем строкам, и во все ячейки в строках, в которых CheckBox.IsChecked записывайте значение из поля ввода.

Comment: можно но лишние действия. желательно на лету сразу делать.

Comment: @Пандакун, вам в любом случае придется проверять в какие строки писать. Как вариант, при создании грида присвойте полям для ввода какие-то идентификаторы, и тогда при вводе в одно из полей в хэндлере опять-таки пробегайте по всем строкам и в те, в которых идентификатор совпадает, пишите.